# How to invoke a method on a foreground service by clicking on a notification action?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications

I have a foreground service. It does some async work in the background and periodically issues a notification asking the user if the work should be stopped.

The notification has a button **"Yes, please"** and when clicked it must invoke `stopAction` method.

The code below is where I'm stuck. I'm maybe way off and this can't be done. Any advice?

**MainService.kt**

```
...

override fun onCreate() {
  subscribeToStopActionRequest()
}

private fun subscribeToStopActionRequest () {
    var eventReceiverHelper = EventReceiverHelper { stopAction() }
    val filter = IntentFilter().apply {
        addAction("${packageName}.stop_action_request")
    }
    registerReceiver(eventReceiverHelper, filter)
}

private fun stopAction () {
  ...
}

private fun showNotification () {
    val intent = Intent(this, EventService::class.java)
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

    var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, state.notificationChannelId)
        .setContentTitle("Want to stop?")
        .addAction(R.drawable.stop_icon, "Yes, please", pendingIntent)
        .build()

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
        notify(1, notification)
    }
}
```

**Event receiver helper**

```
class EventReceiverHelper(val cb: () -> Unit): BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        cb()
    }
}
```

Comment: Create `EventService` as inner class of your `MainService` then you can directly call any method of outer class . Not sure if that's what you are asking ..

Comment: Sorry, the naming was confusing, I renamed `EventService` to `EventReceiverHelper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a constant:

```
private const val EXTRA_STOP = "stop";
```

Then create an intent for your service and put an extra flag:

```
val intent = Intent(context, YourService::class.java);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STOP, true);
```

Now you can create a pending intent as your handler:

```
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

This pending intent will trigger the `onStartCommand` method on your service, where you can check whether the stop flag was set.

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    if (intent != null && intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_STOP, false)) {
        stopAction()
    }
    ...
}
```